# how to use re.compile and re.sub in python?

Tags: python, regex

if I have a dictionary:

```
a = dict(int='111', b=r'aaabbb#int##int#*')
```

I want to use re.compile and re.sub these two functions to convert it to this form :

```
a = {'b': 'aaabbb(111)(111)*', 'int': '111'}
```

This is my code:

```
i = re.compile(r'#.*#')
result = i.match(a[list(a.keys())[0]))
re.sub(r'#.*#',a[list(pat_dict.keys())[0]], result)
```

But the result always return None. I am so confused about it.

How should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: `a = {int='111', b = r'aaabbb#int##int#*'}` not a valid dictionary.

Comment: it should be a = dict( int='111', b = r'aaabbb#int##int#*')

Comment: Don't index dict.keys() to get a value. You have no control over the ordering of the keys. And what is m?

Comment: You can do `a['b'] = re.sub(r'#.*?#', '(%s)' % a['int'], a['b'])` .

Comment: That doesn't work...

Comment: Yes it does...Why wouldn't it?

Comment: it raised :         SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: Then it's because of a syntax error on *your* line of code, not mine. Specifically this line: `a = dict('int'='111', 'b'=r'aaabbb#int##int#*')` is invalid because keywords can't be strings. I've added an answer that shows a complete working example.

Comment: Not sure why both the string to be formatted and the replacement are in the same dictionary. At least if they are separated as format string `format` and a dict `m`, then you can do something like `re.sub('#(' + '|'.join([re.escape(k) for k in m.keys()]) + ')#', lambda x: '(' + m[x.group(1)] + ')' if x.group(1) in m else x.group(), format)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the full, working code:

```
import re

a = dict(int='111', b=r'aaabbb#int##int#*')
expected_a = {'b': 'aaabbb(111)(111)*', 'int': '111'}
a['b'] = re.sub(r'#.*?#', '(%s)' % a['int'], a['b'])

print a == expected_a # True
```

Comment: if the dictionary can be changed, I mean If we don't know the specific key of the dictionary, what should we do?

Comment: @Jign You could always find the right keys according to your logic by iterating through `dict.keys()` or the `dict` itself.